# Standalone script referencing both known and new sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm setting out to write a code to import data in to my active sheet from a master.

The script is standalone - will be an add-on

The active worksheet will be new (variable Id)

The master worksheet has a known/static Id

My solution was to use Logger to record the Id of my active worksheet. I slice the time information off the front, leaving only the Id.
I've run in to two problems with this:

1. Defining sliced logger output as a variable results in blank output. I checked this with:

   ```
   function misc() {
   var wb3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
   var wb2 = Logger.getLog().slice(35,999);
   Logger.log(wb3);
   Browser.msgBox(wb2);
   Logger.clear()
   }
   ```

My message box comes up blank aside from the OK button.
Using Browser.msgBox(Logger.getLog().slice(35,999)) results in a message box with the Id of my sheet, so I can use that instead. Just untidy.

2. Bad value error message when using sliced Logger output

I have written the below a script to copy data from my master:

```
function import() {
var wb1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
Logger.log(wb1);
var ssa = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetById('MASTER_SHEET_ID').getSheetByName("ToTo");            
ssa.getRange('A1:C6').copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.openById(Logger.getLog().slice(35,999)).getSheetByName("ToTo").getRange('A1:C6'))
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Stop chaining so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think a blank dialog is correct.  Try moving Logger.getLog() down one more line.

```
function misc() {
var wb3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
var wb2 = Logger.getLog().slice(35,999);//Nothing in logger yet
Logger.log(wb3);//Now there's something in logger
Browser.msgBox(wb2);
Logger.clear()//Now there's nothing in logger
}
```

I think this is incorrect chaining  you can't get sheet by ID and then getSheetByName.

```
var ssa = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetById('MASTER_SHEET_ID').getSheetByName("ToTo");
```

My advice is don't try to get too fancy with the chaining. It's actually a lot more helpful when debugging code to have access to intermediate variables. And my guess is that everyone debugs there code.

Comment: Totally right about the order, thanks Cooper. I'm currently still putting this together and will update when I've got a working, cleaner version.